# Why do I keep getting this "undefined reference" error?

Tags: c++

```
driver.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "dynStack.h"

using namespace std;

// class definition
int main()
{
  dynstack<int> c1;


  c1.push(1);

  cout<<"hello";

  return 0;
}


dynStack.h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class dynstack
{
    public:
        dynstack();
        void push(T data);


};


dynStack.cc

#include "dynStack.h"

template <class T>
dynstack<T>::dynstack()
{

}

template <class T>
void dynstack<T>::push(T data)
{


    return data;
}
```

I'm new to C++. When I run the code, it keeps giving me "undefined reference to 'dynstack::dynstack()' error. I checked include and prototype and couldn't spot the error. Could anyone help me find where I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `template` classes should have their implementation also in the header file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your templated class methods, unless called from within the same .cpp, need to have their implementations in the header, or an inline file included from the header.

Comment: Or an explicit instantiation in the cpp file.